How to replace bromide with iodide/chloride ligands in organometallic platinum complex?
I have synthesized an organometallic platinum complex, The synthesized complex has two bromide ligands. However, I want to replace these bromide ligands with iodide or chloride ligands. Any suggested method or known method to do so?

A little elaboration on the details of the complex in question could help others answer your question better. As a very surface-level thought, it sounds like you could potentially use the trans effect to your advantage here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans_effect
